# Fade (reduce opacity) image with jQuery only while mouse over

Tags: jquery

I want to turn the opacity of the image to half when it is hovered (and return it to normal when the cursor is not hovering any more).

I only succeed in making all the images `fadeTo`, but when the mouse is out the images still faded (and all the images fade. I just one the image under the cursor to fade).

Any suggestions?

**Code:**

```
    /**
     * Opacity animation of blocks
     */
     $j('#content div a').hover(function() {
         $j('#content div a img').fadeTo('slow', 0.5, function() {
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st thing is that you should use search inside the hovered `a`, so you should use the `this` as the start and then use the [`find`<sup>docs</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method to look under it.

2nd thing is that you need a second handler for [`hover`<sup>docs</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) so you reset the opacity to 1 one hover out..

```
$j('#content div a').hover(
   function() {
         $j(this).find('img').fadeTo('slow', 0.5);
  },
   function() {
         $j(this).find('img').fadeTo('slow', 1);
  }
);
```

Answer (score 3):

With the .hover you need to have two functions, one for mouseover, and one for the mouseleave like so.

```
$j('#content div a img').hover(
    function() {
         $j(this).stop().fadeTo('slow', 0.5);
    },
    function(){
        $j(this).stop().fadeTo('slow', 1);
    }
);
```

I also added a stop, because otherwise you will get weird flickering when hovering over and out multiple times.

**Example**
http://jsfiddle.net/5fJ3H/

Comment: Thanks. This solved my problem. I wanted a menu that on rollover would fade the page content down to 30% opacity. Using the code above it was easy to adapt.